# Teechart. How to delete a text added previously on the chart?

Tags: delphi, teechart

I am adding a text to a chart, using this code:

```
 with form1.Chart1.Tools.Add(TRectangleTool) as TRectangleTool do
  begin
    Text:='THIS A TEXT';
    Shape.Angle:=0;
    Shape.Transparency:=0;
    Shape.Pen.Hide;
    Shape.AutoSize:=True;
    Shape.Color := Talphacolorrec.null;
    Shape.Font.Name:='Segoe UI';
    Shape.Font.Size := 14;
    Shape.Font.Color := Talphacolorrec.red;
    AllowDrag:=False;
    AllowResize:=False;
    Left:= 4;
    Top:= 0;
   
  end;
```

The code works fine. However, later I have to remove it from the chart.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not tested, but I think you should save in form variable the value returned by Add() and then later use it calling IndexOf() to get his index and then call Delete() to remove it. Maybe call Free() as well.

Comment: I did see that Delete() expects an integer number. So your solution seems fine. However, no idea of how to implement it.

Comment: Which part of my explanation you don't understand?

Comment: my knowledge about these chart tools is just the code I wrote. I have trying to implement what you said with no success.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FRectTool := Chart1.Tools.Add(TRectangleTool) as TRectangleTool;
  with FRectTool do begin
    Text:='THIS A TEXT';
    Shape.Angle:=0;
    Shape.Transparency:=0;
    Shape.Pen.Hide;
    Shape.AutoSize:=True;
    Shape.Color := Talphacolorrec.null;
    Shape.Font.Name:='Segoe UI';
    Shape.Font.Size := 14;
    Shape.Font.Color := Talphacolorrec.red;
    AllowDrag:=False;
    AllowResize:=False;
    Left:= 4;
    Top:= 0;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    Index : Integer;
begin
    Index := Chart1.Tools.IndexOf(FRectTool);
    Chart1.Tools.Delete(Index);
    FreeAndNil(FRectTool);  // Not sure it must be called
end;
```

You must declare FRectTool in the form class:

```
  private
    FRectTool: TTeeCustomTool;
```

BTW: I cannot try it myself because I have not TeeChart Pro available. Post a comment to tell if it works or not. If it doesn't work, please publish the errors you get.

Comment: Using private   FRectTool: TTeeCustomTool; FrectTool is not declared. I have to use var FRectTool: TTeeCustomTool;

Comment: Usig Frecttool as a variable, the fist error is in Text :=. The compiler says: '(' expected but ':=' found

Comment: Shape is not recognized either

Comment: @Francisco as I said FRectTool must be defined in the form. Please correctly read my answer. The other errors you mentioned are your own code! Are you telling us that you published not working code?!

Answer (score -1):

```
Var
myrectangle :  array[0..2] of TrectangleTool;
indexrectangle :  array[0..2] of integer;
i, j : integer;

//delete previous Trectangletools
for i := 0 to form1.Chart1.Tools.Count-1 do
    If form1.Chart1.Tools[i] is  TRectangleTool then form1.Chart1.Tools[i].destroy;

//adding two Trectangletools
form1.Chart1.Tools.Add(TRectangleTool);
form1.Chart1.Tools.Add(TRectangleTool);

   j:= -1;

    for i := 0 to form1.Chart1.Tools.Count-1 do
    If form1.Chart1.Tools[i] is  TRectangleTool then
        begin
        inc(j);
        indexRectangle[j] := i;
        myrectangle[i] := form1.Chart1.Tools.Items[i] as TRectangleTool;
        end;

//Defining  the two new Trectangletools
with myrectangle[indexRectangle[0]] do
      begin
        Text :=' 1 this is a text 1';
        Shape.Angle:=0;
        Shape.Transparency:=0;
        Shape.Pen.Hide;
        Shape.AutoSize:=True;
        Shape.Color := Talphacolorrec.null;
       // Shape.Font.Style:=[fsBold];
        Shape.Font.Name:='Segoe UI';
        Shape.Font.Size := 14;
        Shape.Font.Color := Talphacolorrec.Blue;
        AllowDrag:=False;
        AllowResize:=False;
        Left:= 4;
        //Chart1.ChartRect.Left-5;
        Top:= 0;
        //Chart1.ChartRect.Bottom-40;
      end;

      with myrectangle[indexRectangle[1]] do
      begin
        Text :='2 this is a text 2';
        Shape.Angle:=0;
        Shape.Transparency:=0;
        Shape.Pen.Hide;
        Shape.AutoSize:=True;
        Shape.Color := Talphacolorrec.null;
       // Shape.Font.Style:=[fsBold];
        Shape.Font.Name:='Segoe UI';
        Shape.Font.Size := 14;
        Shape.Font.Color := Talphacolorrec.red;
        AllowDrag:=False;
        AllowResize:=False;
        Left:= 200;
        Top:= 0;
       
      end;
```

Comment: Previous code works. First, it searches and deletes previous TrectangleTools. After deleting, then you can add up to 3 new TrectangleTools. Any comments?

Comment: is it '.destroy' a good procedure to delete the TrectangleTool? it works, but I am not so sure.

Comment: This is NOT an answer for your question. You asked how to delete a specific rectangle tool you created, later. Here in you answer, you delete ALL rectangle tools and then add two new. Maybe your question was not correct in which case you should edit it or delete if you discovered it was not your actual problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
 for I := 1 to form1.Chart1.Tools.Count do form1.Chart1.Tools.Delete(0);
```

I found that this is a best way of deleting all the Tools on the chart.

We have to take into account that each time we delete a Tool, at the same moment the Count value drops one unit.

Therefore, we delete the position 0 the number of times required to delete all the Tools.

Comment: That is NOT an answer to your question.